# Fan keeps running indefinitely on Ubuntu after system was temporarily hot

Tags: ubuntu, fan

I have a Toshiba Satellite A305D, on which I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 installed.

On Ubuntu I have fan problems (that I also had with the earlier version of Ubuntu, 10.04). When CPU heat increases, the fan works fine and I feel the air going out is hot, but then the fan keeps running indefinitely for some reason and I feel the air going out isn't hot, so it is supposed to stop.

It is really annoying to have to bear the loud sound of the fan while working for hours. If anyone has had this problem (especially if you have Toshiba Satellite, even better A305D), and had solved this problem, please tell me how you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9197545&postcount=24

Should help out.